# Cardando project idea

Tags: development, learning

I'm currently very interested in getting deeper in web3 and blockchain development. I will have this masters dissertation to which I'd like to propose a project that allowed me to develop some sort of infrastructure or dapp for the Cardano ecosystem.
I have particular interest in infrastructures such as bridges and was thinking about proposing a prototype for a bridge between Cardano and another blockchain such as Cosmos or Polkadot. I know this may be a daunting development process, and definitely not a "one man job". However, do you think this could be a somewhat interesting project to approach from a proof of concept perspective? As a means to engage in this development field, as well as eventually adding value to the ecosystem?

Let me know your thoughts on this, and any suggestions or feedback will be more than welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: So in summary, you are wondering whether or not it would be worth it to do a project where the goal is to build a bridge between Cardano and Cosmos or Polkadot?

Comment: @NikeDattani, yeah that's exacly it :) I am also open to other suggestions for projects, basically all feedback is welcome

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the community. While this stack exchange may not be a good fit for questions that open themselves up for rather subjective answers, I figured this topic (***would people find this project interesting***) may come up often enough to warrant a compilation of resources to better answer and pursue such undertaking.

**Project Catalyst** ([introduced in 2020](https://iohk.io/en/blog/posts/2020/09/16/project-catalyst-introducing-our-first-public-fund-for-cardano-community-innovation/)) is a fund for community innovation. You could gauge the interest on various Cardano community channels (official Telegram, several discord servers, the weekly Project Catalyst town hall, reddit etc) or post a proposal right away on [ideascale](https://cardano.ideascale.com/) during the proposal stage of a Project Catalyst fund. The community-run site https://cardanocataly.st/ has further information and links to additional resources.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I’ve considered some of those options, but found this to be the most straightfoward channel to start with. Nonetheless I’ll give them a try :)